# Check if QColorDialog got cancelled

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, qt5

I'm using a `QColorDialog` in PyQt5 to let the user select a color. My code looks like this:

```
result = QColorDialog.getColor(QColor(self.red, self.green, self.blue))
self.red, self.green, self.blue = result.red(), result.green(), result.blue()
```

This works fine so far, however I am unable to detect whether the user cancelled the dialog.

Even when the dialog is canceled, the returned color is `QColor(0, 0, 0, 255)`, and not `None`, as expected.

Is there a way to detect whether the dialog got canceled using the static `getColor` method? Or do I have to manually construct a `QColorDialog` instance?

Comment: What does [`QColor::isValid`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#isValid) return?

Comment: Ah, that seems to work .. feel free to add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`QColor::isValid`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#isValid) to check if the color returned is a valid color.